# Is there any way in Spring MVC to reset values in model before populating request parameters values?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts, struts-1

We are moving from struts 1.3 framework to spring mvc. In struts framework, we used forms which is of type ActionForm. And we maintain it in session scope. When we navigate through screens(A->B->C), we reset certain properties of form. If we navigate from screen A to B, we pass param x=1, and the same is populated in the form's property 'x'. But before navigating from B to C, we reset x=null, as the screen B doesn't pass the param x and we wouldn't want x to maintain the value collected from screen A.
In Struts, the reset method in the form is called automatically every time before populating parameter.In Spring,the model that we pass to the controller's method needs to be reset before it is populated from request parameters. Do we have anyway to implement similar to this in Spring MVC?

```
 protected void processPopulate(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, ActionForm form, ActionMapping mapping)
        throws ServletException {
        if (form == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Populate the bean properties of this ActionForm instance
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug(" Populating bean properties from this request");
        }

        form.setServlet(this.servlet);
        form.reset(mapping, request);

        if (mapping.getMultipartClass() != null) {
            request.setAttribute(Globals.MULTIPART_KEY,
                mapping.getMultipartClass());
        }

        RequestUtils.populate(form, mapping.getPrefix(), mapping.getSuffix(),
            request);
```

Answer (score 0):

At last, i found the option to call my own reset method in the model before it gets populated with request values. 
I extended ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor and overriden the method bindRequestParameters where i called reset method on model and then routed to method in super class. 
And more over, i registered my implementation class in RequestMappingHandlerAdapter as one of the argument resolver. I collected all the resolvers first, then added mine in the first place in order to avoid the existing resolver to be skipped for ModelAttribute processing.

```
public class ResetArgumentResolver extends ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor {

    @Autowired
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

    ResetArgumentResolver(boolean annotationNotRequired) {
        super(annotationNotRequired);
    }

    ResetArgumentResolver(){
        this(false);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = requestMappingHandlerAdapter.getArgumentResolvers();
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> newArgResolvers = new ArrayList<>();
        newArgResolvers.add(this);
        newArgResolvers.addAll(argumentResolvers);
        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setArgumentResolvers(Collections.unmodifiableList(newArgResolvers));
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindRequestParameters(WebDataBinder binder, NativeWebRequest request) {
        Object attribute = binder.getTarget();
        if (xxxx.class.isAssignableFrom(attribute.getClass())) {
            ((xxxx) attribute).reset();
        }
        super.bindRequestParameters(binder,request);
    }
}
```